vnet data gateway used by power BI statistics and monitoring
The vnet data gateway used within powerBI to integrate a private virtual network in azure, i was wondering where I can get performance statistics information or perhaps a powershell script to get the status of the vnet data gateway.
From the power BI admin page, it shows a status of online, how can one get this programmatically ?

Microsoft have just released this preview feature which allows you to download performance counters related to memory and CPU usage.
I have written a script in python using duckdb to read the performance counter info across the thousands of parquet files and then matplotlib to plot this.
